# $L^{\infty}$ is a normed linear space.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I want to prove that $(L^{\infty}(E), ||f||_{\infty})$ is a normed linear space with norm
$$||f||_{\infty}= \inf\{M\geq0 : |f(x)| \leq M \text{ for almost all } x\in E\},$$
where is a measurable set.

I already proved the triangle inequality. Now, I want to prove that $||f||_{\infty} = 0 \Leftrightarrow f = 0$. Suppose that $||f||_{\infty} = 0$, then 
$$ 0 = \inf\{M\geq0 : |f(x)| \leq M \text{ for almost all } x\in E\},$$
but the infinimum of $M\geq0$ is $0$, so that $|f(x)| \leq 0$, which implies that $|f|=0$ and thus $f=0$ as required. Now, under the assumption that $f = 0$, we have that $|f|=0$ and 
$$||f||_{\infty}= \inf\{M\geq0 : 0 \leq M \text{ for almost all } x\in E\},$$
so that $M =0$ and $||f||_{\infty}=0$ as required. Now, I am having trouble to show that for any real number $\alpha$
$$||\alpha f||_{\infty}=|\alpha|||f||_{\infty}.$$
I have the following 
$$||\alpha f||_{\infty} = \inf\{M\geq0 : |\alpha f(x)| \leq M \text{ for almost all } x\in E\},$$
but then $M\geq 0$ is an infinimum if and only if 
$$\inf\{M\geq0 : |f(x)| \leq \frac{M}{|\alpha|} \text{ for almost all } x\in E\},$$ is an infinimum for $|| f||_{\infty}$. But I do not know how to continue and if this approach is correct.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the right answer. The case of $\alpha=0$ is trivial. Consider $\alpha\neq0$. Then (being a bit loose; you can fill in the details),
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert \alpha f\right\Vert  & =\inf\left\{ M\geq0\colon\left|\alpha f(x)\right|\leq M\text{ for almost all }x\in E\right\} \\
 & =\inf\left\{ M\geq0\colon\left|f(x)\right|\leq\frac{M}{\left|\alpha\right|}\text{ for almost all }x\in E\right\} .
\end{align*}
Making the substitution
$$
M^{\prime}=\frac{M}{\left|\alpha\right|},
$$
we get
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert \alpha f\right\Vert  & =\inf\left\{ \left|\alpha\right|M^{\prime}\geq0\colon\left|f(x)\right|\leq M^{\prime}\text{ for almost all }x\in E\right\} \\
 & =\left|\alpha\right|\inf\left\{ M^{\prime}\geq0\colon\left|f(x)\right|\leq M^{\prime}\text{ for almost all }x\in E\right\} \\
 & =\left|\alpha\right|\left\Vert f\right\Vert .
\end{align*}